# setInterval and its first argument and socket.io emit

Tags: javascript, socket.io, setinterval

I just noticed a strange behavior while using `setInterval`. I'm using `setInterval` to request the server to send data every 2 seconds, and this is what I quite naturally proceeded to do:

```
this.socketInterval = setInterval(this.socketio.emit, 2000, 'persist'); // didn't work
```

I thought it would do the trick as,

```
this.socketio.emit('persist');
```

had worked. Instead it threw an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I got it to work by encapsulating it within a function, but I am still curious about why simply passing `this.socketio.emit` as first argument didn't work.

```
this.socketInterval = setInterval(p => this.socketio.emit(p), 2000, 'persist'); // works!
```

Comment: `this` is wrong within `emit`. Instead: `setInterval(this.socketio.emit.bind(this.socketio), 2000, 'persist')`

Comment: Or with ES2015+: `setInterval(() => this.socketio.emit('persist'), 2000)`